# Print first 6 lines in CSV and then start reading row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I have a CSV and I am trying to print out the first 6 lines of header and then start the code after. I'm super newb. I know how to skip the first 6 lines with next(reader), but I need the first 5 lines to print because it's the header and then start the script at line 8 where the data begins. So I am thinking it's some kind of print statement after reader = and then maybe next(reader) after that to initiate the code. Just my theory.

```
import csv

with open('GAT_US_PartReview_2017-06-23.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)



    for row in reader:
        hqline, part_no, part_class, appl_req, appl_count, intr_req, 
        intr_count, oe_intr, has_oe_intr, has_attr_editor,
        part_IMG_req, has_part_img, has_part_img, has_mpcc, warr_req, 
        warr_txt, warr_pdf, msds_req, has_msds, upc_req, has_upc, 
        has_unspsc, attr_count, attrval_count, valid_part = row
```

[image: CSV Import]

```
Supplier Line:,,Gates Rubber - Denver (GAT),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Summary:,,Parts HQ Abbr,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
ACCT No:,,40013586,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
RecCount:,,10221,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Applicable Date:,,"June 14, 2017 (Wednesday)",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
HQ Line,Part No,Part Class,Appl Req,Appl Count ,Intr Req,Intr Count ,OE Intr Req,Has OE Intr,Has Attr Editor, Has Attr Values,Part IMG Req,Has Part IMG,Has MPCC,Warr Req,Has Warr TXT,Has Warr PDF,MSDS Req,Has MSDS,UPC Req,Has UPC,Has UNSPSC,Attr Count ,AttrVal Count ,Valid Part
GAT,'27210',S,NO,0,YES,1,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,30,13,YES
GAT,'27211',O,NO,0,YES,1,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,30,14,YES
GAT,'27212',S,NO,0,YES,1,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,30,13,YES
GAT,'27213',S,NO,0,YES,1,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,30,13,YES
GAT,'27220',S,NO,0,YES,2,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,35,20,YES
GAT,'27221',S,NO,0,YES,2,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,35,20,YES
```

Comment: Instead of the image.. Can you post some sample output content. So I can copy it and check ?

Comment: Posted...it's kinda ugly looking. let me know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try enumerate?

```
import csv

with open('GAT_US_PartReview_2017-06-23.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row_num, row in enumerate(reader):
        if row_num <= 5:
            print row  # Print out the header
        else:
            hqline, part_no, part_class, appl_req, appl_count, intr_req, 
            intr_count, oe_intr, has_oe_intr, has_attr_editor,
            part_IMG_req, has_part_img, has_part_img, has_mpcc, warr_req, 
            warr_txt, warr_pdf, msds_req, has_msds, upc_req, has_upc, 
            has_unspsc, attr_count, attrval_count, valid_part = row
```

Comment: This works! Just needs some tweeking to get rid of all the ugly apostrophes and commas from the CSV.

Comment: Now the question is getting the script to start running on line 8 lol

Comment: I think you can figure that one out ;)

Comment: trying to convert this to read .xlsx files using xldx. I got it importing and reading the file, but can't seem to figure the right combo for the enumerate to read the workbook.

Comment: You have a few options for reading .xlsx files. You can try [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd),  [openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl) or any other Python Excel library. I would recommend openpyxl as it is more actively maintained. Using openpyxl you should be able to select some range of columns and rows so the task should be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Well simple skip those first six lines then using a simple `if..else`

**Example csv file:**

```
Supplier,  GAT   
Summary, Parts   
ACCT no, 40404
RecCount, 10122
App Date, june 14,2017

HQ,Part No, Part class, Stuff, Other stuff
GAT,'27211',O,NO,0
GAT,'27212',O,YES,0
GAT,'99999',O,NOPE,0
```

**Code:**

```
import csv

stuff = []

with open('test_file.csv', newline='') as f:
    freader = csv.reader(f)
    count=0
    for line in freader:
        count+=1
        if count>6:
            hqline, part_no, part_class, appl_req, appl_count=line
            print(hqline, part_no, part_class, appl_req, appl_count)
        else:
            stuff.append(line)


print("-----------------------------------")
print(stuff)
```

**Output:**

```
HQ Part No  Part class  Stuff  Other stuff
GAT '27211' O NO 0
GAT '27212' O YES 0
GAT '99999' O NOPE 0
-----------------------------------
[['Supplier', '  GAT   '], ['Summary', ' Parts   '], ['ACCT no', ' 40404'], ['RecCount', ' 10122'], ['App Date', ' june 14', '2017'], []]
>>>
```

so basically if count is **less than or equal to** six I'm just appending those unwanted strings to `stuff` list.

```
stuff.append(line)
```

if line is greater than six I'm unpacking them as you wanted.

```
hqline, part_no, part_class, appl_req, appl_count=line
```

Hope this was clear to you.

**Ofcourse** you can print them. I just appended to explain the concept to you.